# Google Earth Engine using Python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

How should a beginner start learning Google Earth Engine coding with python using colab? I know python, but how do I come to know about the objects of images and image classification.

Comment: See the [Developer Guide page on using the Earth Engine Python API in Colab](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-colab.html). See [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install#syntax) for syntax differences between JS and Py related to EE. In the future please ask your GEE questions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine) - see this [page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help) for help options.

Comment: See this repository in [github](https://github.com/csaybar/EEwPython)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/csaybar/EEwPython

https://www.earthdatascience.org/tutorials/intro-google-earth-engine-python-api/

https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/Earth_Engine/

And so, there are lot of resources online to get started with Google Earth Engine in Colab or local python notebooks. Regarding about image classification, you need to first understand the basics of remote sensing, classification type you want to perform(several methods under category of supervised and/or unsupervised, and choose one that best fits your analysis or requirement.).

Similarly, With python notebooks, you can leverage the power or python and its libraries to perform complex analysis and visualizations.
scipy, numpy, arrays, rasterio, matplotlib, geopandas, etc. are some frameworks that you might consider along the way.

Answer (score 1):

i use geemap package for convert shape file to earth engine variable without uploading file on assets

Answer (score 0):

you can access GEE python API easily from these two commands after you are importing ee(explanation in [this link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api)):

- first trigger the authentication:

  ```
  ee.Authenticate()
  ```
- second initialize the library:

  ```
  ee.Initialize()
  ```

in case you face with **AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'**, use this:

```
   import collections
   collections.Callable = collections.abc.Callable
```

In addition, you can use the geemap library for visualization maps which represent in [this link](https://geemap.org/get-started/).